What is the safest way to edit the swiftui String Catalog file directly?
It appears that a comment in my string catalog file causes Xcode to crash when it is rendered in the Source Control Navigator View (yes - it did drive me crazy)
The string is:
"X" : { "comment" : "Represents doubled in header\nfrom contract struct",
which was derived from this source code:
return String(localized: "X",  comment: "Represents doubled in the header")
I suspect the carriage return in the comment is the problem, but I can't remove it.
Clearly, this comment is legacy and no longer matches the swiftui source code, but it won't update so my Xcode crashes when trying to submit.
How can I change this comment in the String catalogue?
I tried editing the json file directly but this is ignored. I tried removing the code line and then reading it but the offending comment returns to the string catalog so I guess it's cached somewhere. I tried cleaning the build folder and repeating the above steps - no success, the comment remains and Xcode crashes.
Can I simply drag and drop a duplicate of the string catalog into my project (with the comment corrected) or will that mess up the project?
Version 15.4 (15F31d) on MacBook Air

"I tried editing the json file directly but this is ignored." You mean the file reverts back after you edit it?

Yes. That's correct. I didn't commit after editing, but I did  inspect the string catalog after building and running the app.

What if you do commit it? Since this only happens in Source Control Navigator View, could it be that it is still trying to display the previous version?

If I commit then Xcode crashes, but the commit is nevertheless effective. I can avoid the problem by resizing Xcode as small as possible before navigating to the SourceControl view.
But I'm hoping that if I could remove the comment from the string catalog (somehow) then the crashes would stop.

The question is answered, but just in case a poor soul also suffers these Xcode 15.4 crashes, here're my workarounds:


Remove the text catalogue from the local git repository using the File App. Works, but obviously only a stop-gap and not recommended.


Avoid the Xcode source control navigator view . Use git in terminal mode or if you're a newbie like me use the git desktop App. That's a simple-workaround.


Here's hooping Apple no longer receives Xcode dumps from me with Xcode 16.


I tried editing the json file directly but this is ignored.

That sounds like the localisation key is still managed automatically by Xcode. I would try switching to manual management first, so that Xcode doesn't update it automatically on every build.
In string catalog view, select "Manual" here

Or in JSON:
{
  "sourceLanguage" : "en",
  "strings" : {
    "Foo" : {
      "comment" : "Some Comment",
      "extractionState" : "manual", // <----
      "localizations" : {
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "version" : "1.0"
}


This answers the question exactly. I can't say whether it solves the crashes (dumps with my description are with Apple) but this is exactly what I was looking for and hadn't found in the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/localizing-and-varying-text-with-a-string-catalog .
